# How to configure npm package to auto-update

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json

I have made this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-notifications

When I run `npm install nestjs-notifications --save` it will install ok and add to the registry, but will save it as:

```json
"nestjs-notifications": "0.0.10"
```

How do I configure it to so it will install with semantic version as:

```json
"nestjs-notifications": "^0.0.10".
```

Currently I can't pick up the new version automatically, I have to manually change the version in package.json.

---

**Edit:** My pertinent [config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config) settings are as follows (essentially they're default). So it should be saving with a caret:

```
save = true
save-bundle = false
save-dev = false
save-exact = false
save-optional = false
save-prefix = "^"
save-prod = false
...
```

Comment: Is there anything in your `npm config` setting the `save-prefix` or `save-exact`? The default is to use the caret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're encountering is expected behavior. Installing any pkg with a `0.0.x` semver doesn't get the default caret (`^`) prefix in *package.json*, nor will your package be updated.

In the npm docs for [caret ranges](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) it states:

> *"Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the `[major, minor, patch]` tuple. In other words, this allows patch and minor updates for versions `1.0.0` and above, patch updates for versions `0.X >=0.1.0`, **and no updates for versions `0.0.X`**."*

<sub>**Note** The bold emphasis in the excerpt (above) was added by me.</sub>

Essentially once you've bumped your package's semver to `>=0.1.0` only then will you begin to get the desired behavior.

---

**Demonstration showing when the caret (`^`) IS and IS NOT added to package.json:**

1. Install a version of a package that is `<0.1.0`. For demo purposes we'll install [eslint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint) version `0.0.7` by running the following command:

   ```
   npm i eslint@0.0.7 --save
   ```

   The preceding command adds the following to *package.json*:

   ```json
   "eslint": "0.0.7"
   ```

   <sub>**Note** The caret (`^`) was not included.</sub>
2. Now uninstall `eslint` by running the following command:

   ```
   npm un eslint --save
   ```
3. Next install the first version available of `eslint` that is `>=0.1.0`, i.e run the following:

   ```
   run npm i eslint@0.1.0 --save
   ```

   This time the preceding command adds the following to package.json::

   ```json
   "eslint": "^0.1.0"
   ```

   <sub>**Note** The caret (`^`) has been included.</sub>